# How do I segue from a row and display the name of the row in the new view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates

I'm building a task timer app, and I am prodding around with it to see what works and doesn't work. I'm a beginner and I'm not sure how to tackle this problem. What I am trying to have happen is for the user to be able to click on a table row which segues directly to the timer view controller and for the string value in the selected row to display in a label on the timer view controller. I've tried to do this in a few different ways but can't wrap my head around the different techniques.

Here's the view controller for my timer

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var pauseButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var startButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var timerTaskLabel: UILabel!


var seconds = 10
var timer = Timer()
var isTimerRunning = false
var resumeTapped = false

@IBAction func cancel(_ sender: Any) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func startButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    if isTimerRunning == false {
        runTimer()
        self.startButton.isEnabled = false
    }
}

func runTimer() {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: (#selector(ViewController.updateTimer)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    isTimerRunning = true
    pauseButton.isEnabled = true
}

@IBAction func pauseButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if self.resumeTapped == false {
        timer.invalidate()
        self.resumeTapped = true
        self.pauseButton.setTitle("Resume",for: .normal)
    } else {
        runTimer()
        self.resumeTapped = false
        self.pauseButton.setTitle("Pause",for: .normal)
    }
}

@IBAction func resetButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    timer.invalidate()
    seconds = 60
    self.timerLabel.text = timeString(time: TimeInterval(seconds))
    if self.resumeTapped == true {
        self.resumeTapped = false
        self.pauseButton.setTitle("Pause",for: .normal)
    }
    isTimerRunning = false
    pauseButton.isEnabled = false
    startButton.isEnabled = true
}

func updateTimer() {
    if seconds < 1 {
        timer.invalidate()
        //Send alert to indicate "time's up!"
    } else {
        seconds -= 1
        timerLabel.text = timeString(time: TimeInterval(seconds))
    }
}

func timeString(time:TimeInterval) -> String {
    let hours = Int(time) / 3600
    let minutes = Int(time) / 60 % 60
    let seconds = Int(time) % 60
    return String(format:"%02i:%02i:%02i", hours, minutes, seconds)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    pauseButton.isEnabled = false
    self.timerLabel.text = timeString(time: TimeInterval(seconds))
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}





override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

and here is the code for my table view

```
import UIKit

class TaskListViewController: UITableViewController, 
AddNewTaskViewControllerDelegate {

var tasks: [TaskData]

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    tasks = [TaskData]()

    let row0item = TaskData()
    row0item.task = "learn French"
    row0item.time = "500"
    tasks.append(row0item)

    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

//DELEGATE PROTOCOLS
func addNewTaskViewControllerDidCancel(_ controller: AddNewTaskViewController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
func addNewTaskViewController(_ controller: AddNewTaskViewController, didFinishAdding item: TaskData) {
    let newRowIndex = tasks.count
    tasks.append(item)
    print("\(item.time)")

    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: newRowIndex, section: 0)
    let indexPaths = [indexPath]
    tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .automatic)

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "AddTask" {
        let navigationController = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
        let controller = navigationController.topViewController as! AddNewTaskViewController
        controller.delegate = self
    }
}
//DELEGATE PROTOCOLS



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    tasks.remove(at: indexPath.row)

    let indexPaths = [indexPath]
    tableView.deleteRows(at: indexPaths, with: .automatic)
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tasks.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TaskListItem", for: indexPath)

    let taskItem = tasks[indexPath.row]
    let label = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
    label.text = taskItem.task
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated...I hope this question makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to pass a string value from one view to another when it segues. One way you could do it is create a string variable in your timer view controller and on your other view before it segues to the timer view have it set that variable to whatever the display text from the row is. Then on the timer view controller you can just use that variable now since it was set by the guy calling that segue. (In the override func prepare(segue...) method)

Sorry for not writing any code, i'm not in an environment currently where I can.

Comment: Thanks this seems to be working so far...I'm just getting a wrong type error when I try to assign TaskData to UILabel